# Best way to configure the cookies for different environments

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem with my configuration. So my site have 3 environments: dev,pp and p.
I want to configure the cookies to work for any of this environments.
I tried:

```
return array(
'cookie'    => array(
    'domain'   => '.test.dev.dev',
    'path'     => '/',
    'lifetime' => 0,
),
);
```

For dev my link is like this: .test.dev.dev

For pp: test.pp.com

For p is p.com

For my solution it works only for dev environment but I want that it works for any.

Answer (score 0):

To work on all the domains , set domain as default , so that cookie will be enable for all the domains.The e.g is given below

```
return array(
'cookie'    => array(
    'domain'   => null,
    'path'     => '/',
    'lifetime' => 0,
),
);
```